# Removing bottom border of particular td

Tags: html

I have a table which is like[image]
      You can see the border below Operation Research, under the course column. I want that border to be removed, but the code I've written is not working, what exactly should I do?

```html
    <html>
     <body>
      <table width="100%" border="1" rules="cols" style="border-collapse : collapse;">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" width="54%" style="border : solid thin;">Courses</td>
        <td align="center" width="23%" style="border : solid thin;">CGPA</td>
        <td align="center" width="23%" style="border : solid thin;">Credit</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>English Language Course</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Additional Language Course<br>&nbsp;French</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Foundation Course</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Core Course<br>Physics<br>&nbsp;Physics</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Complementary Course(s) <br>&nbsp;Mathematics <br>&nbsp;Chemsitry </td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom : none;">Open Course <br>&nbsp;Operations Research</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom : solid thin;">8.1</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom : solid thin;">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="35px">
        <td></td>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">Semester wise SCPA</td>
       </tr>   
      </table>
      <table width="100%">
       <tr>
        
       </tr>   
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just to clarify: exactly wich border do you want to be removed? you're using style settings and borders so why don't you change those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is border of table you have to remove that.

Use following code

```html
<html>
     <body>
      <table width="100%" border="1" rules="cols" style="border : none;">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" width="54%" style="border : solid thin;">Courses</td>
        <td align="center" width="23%" style="border : solid thin;">CGPA</td>
        <td align="center" width="23%" style="border : solid thin;">Credit</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>English Language Course</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Additional Language Course<br>&nbsp;French</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Foundation Course</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Core Course<br>Physics<br>&nbsp;Physics</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Complementary Course(s) <br>&nbsp;Mathematics <br>&nbsp;Chemsitry </td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom : none;">Open Course <br>&nbsp;Operations Research</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom : solid thin;">8.1</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom : solid thin;">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="35px">
        <td></td>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="border : solid thin;">Semester wise SCPA</td>
       </tr>   
      </table>
      <table width="100%">
       <tr>
        
       </tr>   
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the `border-bottom` of `main table` then just set it's `border-bottom:none;` as below,

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" rules="cols" style="border-collapse : collapse;border-bottom:none">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" width="54%" style="border : solid thin;">Courses</td>
        <td align="center" width="23%" style="border : solid thin;">CGPA</td>
        <td align="center" width="23%" style="border : solid thin;">Credit</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>English Language Course</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Additional Language Course<br>&nbsp;French</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Foundation Course</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Core Course<br>Physics<br>&nbsp;Physics</td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Complementary Course(s) <br>&nbsp;Mathematics <br>&nbsp;Chemsitry </td>
        <td align="center">8.1</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom : none;">Open Course <br>&nbsp;Operations Research</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom : solid thin;">8.1</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom : solid thin;">19</td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="35px">
        <td></td>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="border-bottom:solid thin">Semester wise SCPA</td>
       </tr>   
      </table>
      <table width="100%">
       <tr>
        
       </tr>   
      </table>
```

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran If you don't want to remove fully border as added later  then yes sure I will add that for td border-bottom:solid thin.